# Download when idle/low network utilization

Tags: c#, .net, http, optimization, download

I have an update service that needs to pull data down from remote, however like Microsoft's BITS I'd like to do this when the user is idle and/or when their network utilisation is low so as to not impact on their experience.

What do I need to do or look at? Can anyone point me in the right direction on where to start with this and get the information I need?

Comment: Forgive me for not saying, I CANNOT use BITS for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use BITS because you want to be cross-platform, you're going to have trouble. Each OS will have different ways to find the current network usage, so you will have to write an interface class with implementations for each supported OS.

In Linux it seems to be the special file `/proc/net/snmp`. In Windows, BSD or OSX I have no idea. The `netstat -s` shell command seems to work on all of them, but the output format is different for each one.

Answer (score 2):

Use official BITS wrapper http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997639.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about [SharpBITS.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/sharpbits)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363160(VS.85).aspx) where it describes how to use the BITS COM interfaces?

Another article [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/using-bits-to-upload-files-with-.net/) describing how to use BITS with .Net